# Multiple d3 charts on one page

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a cubism d3 chart on my page. I also want to add more charts to the page. Is it possible to add more d3 charts in the same page or will i have to use some other libraries?

I am asking this because every visualization in d3 uses .axis and if i give some style to cubism graph then it would affect other graphs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend wrapping the entire generating code in a function which specifies which DOM element you want to put the chart in as a parameter. This will leverage javascript closure and everything should work itself out.

Comment: I originally thought the concern was that it was hard to tell if d3.svg.axis() was keeping state since it returns a closure, (but creating 2 they seem not to.) But I think the question is just getting overlapping CSS from different examples.